# In-memory created Zip file is corrupted

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, flask, zip

I am trying to serve a zip file (created in-memory by Flask) to a JS front-end. The file downloaded is corrupted and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
@app.route('/route')
def test_zip():
    zf = BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zf, 'w') as archive:
        archive.writestr("test.csv", "test, 2")
    zf.seek(0)
    return send_file(
        zf,
        attachment_filename='test.zip',
        mimetype='application/x-zip-compressed',
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

```javascript
$http({
    url: settings.BACKEND_URL + "/route"
}).success(function (data) {
    var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
    var blob = new Blob([data], {'type': 'application/zip'});
    anchor.attr({
         href: window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
         target: '_blank',
         download: 'test.zip'
    })[0].click();
})
```

The error I get (on Mac OS X) is the following:

```
26 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [test.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a hex editor to compare the downloaded file versus the generated file?

Comment: @RandomDavis I am not sure what you mean, since the file is generated in memory.

Comment: Add code to save `zf` to a local file before sending it, then compare.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, I forgot to mention that if I store the file in the filesystem first, then everything works. What I want to understand is in fact what goes wrong when I try to keep everything in memory.

Comment: The python part works for me. What is data in the success-function?

Comment: that's the body of the response

Comment: what's the contents of the `data` variable?

Comment: @Daniel: If I console.log(data), I see some binary like `PK8��H��7�test.csvtest,2PK8��H��7��test.csvPK6,`

Comment: that is the same I get if I do `print zf.read()` in the backend before sending it

Comment: Have you inspected the downloaded file with a hex editor yet?  You may find something meaningful in those extra 26 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the Python part works just fine. The solution to fix the JS part was to add

```
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

in the arguments of the http request.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data